# BeautifulSoup XML to CSV

Tags: python, xml, pandas, beautifulsoup

The code below takes an xml files and parses it into  csv file.

```
import openpyxl    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('1last.xml') as f_input:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_input, 'lxml')

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Sheet1"

ws.append(["Description", "num", "text"])

for description in soup.find_all("description"):
    ws.append(["", description['num'], description.text])

ws.append(["SetData", "x", "value", "xin", "xax"])

for setdata in soup.find_all("setdata"):
    ws.append(["", setdata.get('x', ''), setdata.get('value', ''), setdata.get('xin', ''), setdata.get('xax', '')])

wb.save(filename="1last.csv")
```

This is output

[image: Here]

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectData>
<FINAL>
    <START id="ID0001" service_code="0x5196">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>225196</Rational>
        <Qualify>6251960000A0DE</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="1213f2312">The parameter</Description>
      <DataFile dg="12" dg_id="let">
        <SetData value="32" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
    <START id="DG0003" service_code="0x517B">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>23423</Rational>
        <Qualify>342342</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="3423423f3423">The third</Description>
      <DataFile dg="55" dg_id="big">
        <SetData x="E1" value="21259" />
        <SetData x="E2" value="02" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
    <START id="ID0048" service_code="0x5198">
      <RawData rawdata_type="START">
        <Rational>225198</Rational>
        <Qualify>343243324234234</Qualify>
      </RawData>
      <Description num="434234234">The forth</Description>
      <DataFile unit="21" unit_id="FEDS">
        <Ycross unit="ce" points="21" name="Thefiles" text_id="54" unit_id="98" 
        <SetData xin="5" xax="233" value="323" />
        <SetData xin="123" xax="77" value="555" />
        <SetData xin="17" xax="65" value="23" />
      </DataFile>
    </START>
</FINAL>
</ProjectData>
```

Recently I have been trying to modify the code so it goes through all the children of *START* and parse them into columns. If one child element has more rows, it will parse into a new line just as what the code above does. Unfortunately, not successful and just stuck at this moment

This picture shows on how the output should look like.
[image: Here]

Comment: Why are you using openpyxl? wouldn't using `csv` module be so much easier, as you are trying to create a csv file?

Comment: @DeepSpace, I updated my answer, Not sure if it the right approach but it gives me a csv file as an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

I have written the code for only a few of the tags. You can easily fill up the rest of the required tags similarly. Hope it helps!

**Edited** to add the set data tag values.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

tree = ET.parse(StringIO(data))
root = tree.getroot()

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    start_nodes = root.findall('.//START')
    headers = ['id', 'service_code', 'rational', 'qualify', 'description_num', 'description_txt', 'set_data_xin', 'set_data_xax', 'set_data_value', 'set_data_x']
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for sn in start_nodes:
        row = defaultdict(str)

        for k,v in sn.attrib.items():
            row[k] = v

        for rn in sn.findall('.//Rational'):
            row['rational'] = rn.text

        for qu in sn.findall('.//Qualify'):
            row['qualify'] = qu.text

        for ds in sn.findall('.//Description'):
            row['description_txt'] = ds.text
            row['description_num'] = ds.attrib['num']

        # all other tags except set data must be parsed before this.
        for st in sn.findall('.//SetData'):
            for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                row['set_data_'+ str(k)] = v
            row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
            writer.writerow(row_data)
            row = defaultdict(str)
```

**Update**

add

```
        for st in sn.findall('.//DataFile'):
            for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                row['datafile_'+ str(k)] = v 

        for st in sn.findall('.//Ycross'):
            for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                row['ycross_'+ str(k)] = v
```

and the corresponding values to the `headers` list

Comment: I'm sorry but your code doesn't even show the columns names and the part where I was struggling which was when going to a new row if there are more than one row of SetData. The picture on my output shows what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: the picture you have shown is an excel file. csv file will not have such formating options. it will be just rows of comma separated values.

Comment: To add header row, it is just a one liner `writer.writerow(headers) # write the header row.`. I have added that to the answer now.

Comment: If what you want is an excel file then you should use `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter` package. I gave this solution because tile of your post says xml to csv

Comment: The picture above is just the way it should look the formatting. I checked the code now. It is working just getting  an empty line between the rows with information. Still having the problem with _SetData_ . It is really important for the SetData o be constructed the the pic from above.

Comment: added code to read the set data and remove the extra new line. hope it helps

Comment: the first part of the picture show the result I'm getting using ur code the second part starting from row 10 shows how it should look like. Link to screenshot https://ibb.co/brBpb0L

Comment: @ebe: Please avoid adding more things to a question after you have received an answer that works. Mark the answer as accepted. If there is a remaining problem, please ask a new question that deals with only that problem.

Comment: @abhilb, Can you just help me with how I would add **DataFile**, **Ycross**  and their attributes . Based on your comment on the code I know how to add other tags but these have attributes just like SetData

Comment: @abhilb Happy New Year. I have been trying to change to code from above and make it so that it parses many xml files instead of one into one csv file. Unfortunately, I have been facing trouble, if you have time please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554463/parse-many-xml-file-to-one-csv-file