# Parse many XML files to one CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, elementtree

The code below takes an XML file and parses specific elements into a CSV file. Regarding the code I had simpler and different code that had a slightly different out, the code below is as an outcome of a lot help from here.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

tree = ET.parse('thexmlfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    start_nodes = root.findall('.//START')
    headers = ['id', 'service_code', 'rational', 'qualify', 'description_num', 'description_txt', 'set_data_xin', 'set_data_xax', 'set_data_value', 'set_data_x']
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for sn in start_nodes:
        row = defaultdict(str)

        for k,v in sn.attrib.items():
            row[k] = v

        for rn in sn.findall('.//Rational'):
            row['rational'] = rn.text

        for qu in sn.findall('.//Qualify'):
            row['qualify'] = qu.text

        for ds in sn.findall('.//Description'):
            row['description_txt'] = ds.text
            row['description_num'] = ds.attrib['num']

        # all other tags except set data must be parsed before this.
        for st in sn.findall('.//SetData'):
            for k,v in st.attrib.items():
                row['set_data_'+ str(k)] = v
            row_data = [row[i] for i in headers]
            writer.writerow(row_data)
            row = defaultdict(str)
```

I'm trying to make that this code goes to a folder that has many XML files and parses them into one single CSV file. Simply said instead of parsing one XML file , do this for multiple XMLs and parse them to one csv file.

What I would normally do is use os.listdir(): . The code would look something like this

```
directory = 'C:/Users/docs/FolderwithXMLs'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        #Something here
        df.to_csv("./output.csv")
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

I have tried different ways to implement this into the code from above without success until now. Considering that this process should also be fast.

Comment: @abhilb; struggling to implement the function above so it iterates through multiple xml files

Comment: What is the issue here?#

Comment: @abhilb, I would like that the code you wrote instead of parsing only one XML file to do so with many XML file and parse them to one CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from pathlib import Path

directory = 'C:/Users/docs/FolderwithXMLs'

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    headers = ['id', 'service_code', 'rational', 'qualify', 'description_num', 'description_txt', 'set_data_xin', 'set_data_xax', 'set_data_value', 'set_data_x']

    writer.writerow(headers)

    xml_files_list = list(map(str,Path(directory).glob('**/*.xml')))
    for xml_file in xml_files_list:
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()

        start_nodes = root.findall('.//START')
        for sn in start_nodes:
            row = defaultdict(str)

            # <<<<< Indentation was wrong here
            for k,v in sn.attrib.items():
                row[k] = v

            # Rest of the code here.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the full code  https://controlc.com/586d041e. I tried it with two two xmls files that are the same just different numbers same structure. Here is a photo of the ouput which seems to parse only specific part and on the side is the xml also https://ibb.co/rdSgykr

Comment: indentation of the for loop was wrong. fixed that now