# How to put text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am working on parsing an `.xml` file. I need to convert to a `.csv` Person file: `names.txt`.

e.g.:

`names.txt`:

```
anna
james
miray
vill
```

`XML file:`

```xml
<data>
    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <person>name1</person>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>  
            <person>name2</person>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>
            <person>name3</person>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>
</data>
```

Comment: first link on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514690/beautifulsoup-xml-to-csv) explains the convertion from `.xml` to `.csv`. In your case is a `.csv` with only 1 column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example_string = '<data><AAA><CCC><person>name1</person></CCC><CCC><person>name2</person></CCC><CCC><person>name3</person></CCC></AAA></data>'

# Here I hard code the list of names. My assumption is you already know how
# to read the names from names.txt into a list.
names = ['anna', 'james', 'miray']

# Parse the XML into a BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(example_string, 'lxml-xml')

# Replace the content of each 'person' tag
for name, item in zip(names, soup.find_all('person')):
    item.string = name

# Pretty-print the XML after modifications
print(soup.prettify())
```

This will have the following output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
 <AAA>
  <CCC>
   <person>
    anna
   </person>
  </CCC>
  <CCC>
   <person>
    james
   </person>
  </CCC>
  <CCC>
   <person>
    miray
   </person>
  </CCC>
 </AAA>
</data>
```

Comment: This answer correctly answered the question at the time it was written. Since then the question was updated to ask for something very different. Please do not downvote my answer.

Comment: @villwocki Why did you accept my answer, after your question was edited? Whoever edited your question has changed it enough that my answer no longer answers the new version of the question.